# Android Studio Unknown Unicode font?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

I use android studio 3.0.1 in window, but in my string resource not show original language!

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you use default font in IDE and Editor settings?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Hopefully it helps
[image]

Comment: sorry sir, where is it?

Comment: At the bottom of Android Studio

Comment: ohh, I see sir, but It's UTF-8 like you

Comment: What is the language of strings?

Comment: Khmer language sir

Comment: Before I update IDE, It working well but after updated, it unknown

Comment: What font do you use? Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Color Scheme Font -> Font

Comment: font monospaced